# Getting error while switching to Linux Container in docker

Tags: docker, windows-10, docker-for-windows, linux-containers

I have installed docker. When its running in windows container it works fine. But if i switch to Linux container getting below error.

Os: Windows 10
Docker Desktop: 2.2.0.3

Error:

```
Docker.Core.Backend.BackendDestroyException:
Unable to stop Hyper-V VM: Service 'Hyper-V Host Compute Service (vmcompute)' cannot be started due to the following error: Cannot start service vmcompute on computer '.'.
at Enable-MobyLinuxRequiredService, <No file>: line 103
at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 804
   at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeClient.<TrySendAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeClient.Send(String action, Object[] parameters)
   at Docker.Actions.<>c__DisplayClass39_0.<SwitchDaemon>b__0()
   at Docker.ApiServices.TaskQueuing.TaskQueue.<>c__DisplayClass18_0.<.ctor>b__1()
```

Comment: i have tried this but vmcompute.exe is not available under "program settings" list.

Answer (score 7):

according to [this](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/3597#issuecomment-474949164)

try the following:

```
1, Open "Window Security"
2, Open "App & Browser control"
3, Click "Exploit protection settings" at the bottom
4, Switch to "Program settings" tab
5, Locate "C:\WINDOWS\System32\vmcompute.exe" in the list and expand it
6, Click "Edit"
7, Scroll down to "Code flow guard (CFG)" and uncheck "Override system settings"
8, Start vmcompute from powershell "net start vmcompute"
```

Comment: unable to find vmcompute.exe (step5) in the list

Comment: it should be there , try to search for it .

Comment: It helped, Can you explain what was the trick? What is Code flow guard (CFG) and whatis the impact?

Answer (score 0):

I think there was a problem with the latest update. People are having the same issue with version 2.2.0.3 (42716), as mentioned [here](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/5834)

Attempts that did not worked for me

1. Disabled control flow guard https://stackoverflow.com/a/60313592/1027250 (bring it back if it doesn't work)
2. Disable Linux subsystem ([git issue](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/5744#issuecomment-586216439)).
3. Re-installation.

**What worked for me is a factory reset**, as suggested [here](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/5834#issuecomment-590852732). Uninstallation doesn't seem to wipe the settings,

Comment: Do you mean a Windows Factory reset?

Comment: @TomDane - There is an option in Docker Desktop that allows you to do a factory reset.